# General formula to compute the redshift (first order perturbations)

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, perturbation-theory, gravitational-redshift

Consider an expanding universe with the following metric in conformal time/co-moving coordinates:

$$ds^2=a^2\left[-c^2\left(1+\frac{2\phi}{c^2}\right)d\eta^2+\left(1-\frac{2\phi}{c^2}\right)\left(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2\right)\right]$$

What would be the formula to compute the redshift $1+z=\frac{\nu_S}{\nu_O}$ of a photon knowing ($\lambda$ is the affine parameter):

- $[\eta_O, x_O, y_O, z_O]$, $[\frac{d\eta_O}{d\lambda}, \frac{dx_O}{d\lambda}, \frac{dy_O}{d\lambda}, \frac{dz_O}{d\lambda}]$, $a_O$, $\phi_O$ for the observer
- $[\eta_S, x_S, y_S, z_S]$, $[\frac{d\eta_S}{d\lambda}, \frac{dx_S}{d\lambda}, \frac{dy_S}{d\lambda}, \frac{dz_S}{d\lambda}]$, $a_S$, $\phi_S$ for the source

and considering that neither the observer nor the source have peculiar velocities regarding to the background.

Comment: A good source is carroll's lecture notes: http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9712019v1.pdf. Especially around eqn 8.61-8.67. He uses a different coordinate system but of course that doesn't really matter. One thing he glosses over (but you point out) is you should parameterize the photon path with an affine parameter.